# Djanog statics are not loading

Tags: python, django, static

I'm trying to run my Django project on localhost server (with runserver command) but my css files are not loading with the error :
Refused to apply style from 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/statics/main.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

I've setup

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATIC_ROOT= BASE_DIR / 'static'

MEDIA_URL = 'media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "statics/css/",
]
```

in settings.py file and put my css files in `BASE_DIR / statics/css/`
but still I've got the error
I also added these setting to the url pattern in urls.py file:

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```